# How to update value in formik with redux

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, formik, yup

I'm having trouble updating Formik with the value I have from redux.

This is my mapPropsToValues:

```
mapPropsToValues(props) {
    const {bid: {total=42, token_quantity: quantity= null}} = props
    return { total, quantity }
  }
```

I've also included `enableReinitialize: true`

The way I have it hooked up is that total and token_quantity are both values i get back from redux and i need to populate them from the store.

My validation schema for total is:

```
total: Yup.number().required('Required')
```

And my Field component is:

```
<Field name="total" type="text" />
```

The way my code works is that when a user clicks a button an action is dispatch and then the store returns `total` and `quantity`. The first time it works perfectly and the value is displayed in the field. The issue I'm having is that if the user then types in the field, no matter if the they click the button afterwards, the value doesn't get updated. There seem to be two calls to `setFeildValue`, one with the value from redux, and then other with the value the user enters which is displayed.'

[image: redux and formik state]

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong as i can't get it to work and I've spent two days on it.